# Find $\angle {GAC}$ in the following figure

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

> In triangle $ABC$ the excircle of $A$ is tangent to sides $BC$ at $D$ and to extensions of $AB$ and $AC$ at points $E$ and $F$ respectively.If $ED$ intersects outer angle bisector of $C$ at $G$ find $\angle {GAC}$.
>   [image]

I have found that: $\angle E=\frac{\angle B}{2}$ and $\angle ACG=90-\frac{\angle C}{2}$ but can't go further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the center of the excircle be $O$. Then $\angle BED = \angle BDE = \angle GDC = \frac{\beta}{2}$, so from the triangle $CDG$ - using that $\angle DCG=\gamma+90^{\circ}-\frac{\gamma}{2}=90^{\circ}+\frac{\gamma}{2}$ - $$\angle DGC =180^{\circ}-\frac{\beta}{2}-(90^{\circ}+\frac{\gamma}{2})=\frac{\alpha}{2}.$$ Also, $\angle EAO=\frac{\alpha}{2}$. Thus the quadrilateral $AGOE$ is cyclic. Since $\angle AEO$ is a right angle, also $\angle AGC$ is a right angle. So from the right triangle $AGC$ we get that $\angle GAC=\frac{\gamma}{2}$.

Comment: Presumably you meant:
$$\angle BED = \angle BDE = \angle GDC = \frac{\beta}{2}$$

Comment: Edited, thanks!

Comment: Why is $\angle AOE=\frac{\alpha}{2}$? Isn't it $\angle OAE=\frac{\alpha}{2}$?

Comment: A typo, again...

Comment: How do you infer that quadrilateral $AGOE$ is cyclic?

Comment: $\angle EAO=\angle EGO=\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: Got it! Very nice.

Comment: @Sz_Z What is $\gamma$?

Comment: The angles of the triangle $ABC$ are $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, as usual.